# ValueError at /post/new/ Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject:<User: chetan>>": "Post.author" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error "ValueError at /post/new/
Cannot assign ">": "Post.author" must be a "User" instance."

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('User.User',related_name="posts",on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank = True,null =True)

    def update(self):
        updated_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

```
views.py

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # form_class = forms.PostForm
    fields = ['text',]
    model = Post

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You here made two `User` objects, the `User` object from `django.contrib.auth` and one from the `User` app. In order to retrieve the related `User` object from the `User` app, you can use `self.request.user.user` (given you of course constructed that related object):

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # form_class = forms.PostForm
    fields = ['text',]
    model = Post

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.author = self.request.user.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

It is however very confusing to name two models the same. It might be better to just use `Profile` for example. In that case it would be `form.instance.author = self.request.user.profile` which is also more readable.